# How To Display ST_AsMVT tiles in Leaflet

Tags: postgis, leaflet, vector-tiles, pbf

I have a large polygon dataset in PostGIS I would like to display in Leaflet map.  I understand st_asmvt() query will return mapbox vector tiles.  I can successfully query the data in postgis but I dont know how to display the results as vector tile layer in leaflet.

Research has lead me to think I should use the [leafletvectorgrid](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid) plugin. Which allows me to display pbf data. How do I construct this url to render the results of my query?

```js
\\my best guess for a local pbf tile url
var pbfTileUrl = "https://localhost/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf?";
var pbfTileLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(pbfTileUrl);
```

The query below returns bytea result.

```sql
SELECT ST_AsMVT(q, 'small_areas', 4096, 'geom')
FROM (
  SELECT ogc_fid, edname, small_area,
    ST_AsMvtGeom(
      wkb_geometry,
      --xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, srid
      --_northEast: o.LatLng {lat: 51.900647154116314, lng: -8.291244506835938}
      --_southWest: o.LatLng {lat: 51.89217277879109, lng: -8.625640869140625}`
      ST_MakeEnvelope(-8.625640,51.892172,-8.291244,51.900647, 4326 )
    ) AS geom
  FROM small_areas
  WHERE wkb_geometry && ST_MakeEnvelope(-8.625640,51.892172,-8.291244,51.900647, 4326 )
  AND ST_Intersects(wkb_geometry, ST_MakeEnvelope(-8.625640,51.892172,-8.291244,51.900647, 4326 ))
) AS q;
```

How do I pass these results to leaflet?

Comment: Have a look at the following resources: https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles and https://github.com/wdtinc/mapbox-vector-tile-java. It seems there is no straightforward method to achieve what you want.

Comment: See https://github.com/pramsey/minimal-mvt (but is uses OpenLayers).